# backbone.js: code for calling function from nested view doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have made the following code, which runs without errors, but after I press the button, it makes an error: tabClicked is not defined.

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

    },

    tabClicked: function(winID) {
         alert("test");
    }
});

var BottomPanel = MainView.extend( {
    initialize: function() {
        $("body").append($(this.el));
        this.$el.attr("id", "bottomPanel").attr("top", "300px").attr("left", "50px");
        this.$el.append($("<button>").click(this.func1));
    },
    func1: function() {
        tabClicked(0);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    var mainView = new MainView();
    var bottomPanel = new BottomPanel();
});
```

I made a child window "BottomPanel" of the parent window "MainView". 
And my intention was to call a method of MainView from BottomPanel Object.
How to do it?

EDIT 1:
I have changed the code above in one line:

```
this.$el.append($("<button>").click(this.tabClicked));
```

Now it works, but I need to save the context. Now **this** variable when button is clicked points not to the mainView object.

Answer (score 2):

It should be this.tabClicked() otherwise javascript looks at the global namespace where tabClicked is not defined.

Comment: No, I tried, but it shows another error after clicking the button: Uncaught type error: Object #<HtmlButtonElement> has no method tabClicked